Spring Boot starter - OTEL cannot send data to otel-collector
I do have very basic configuration of Spring Boot (3.4.0) application with opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter and otel collector.
Unfortunately when I try to send metrics and logs to local Otel collector I do get this error:
2024-12-02T13:45:37.578+01:00 ERROR 41207 --- [alhost:4318/...] i.o.exporter.internal.http.HttpExporter  : Failed to export logs. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Broken pipe

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
        (...)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:4318/...
                at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:210) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
                at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:93) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
                ... 14 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
                at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:335)
                at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
                at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:180)
                ... 16 common frames omitted

2024-12-02T13:45:37.582+01:00 DEBUG 41207 --- [_WorkerThread-1] i.o.s.l.e.BatchLogRecordProcessor$Worker : Exporter failed

Gradle dependencies do contain:
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter")

application.yml does have:
management:
    endpoints.web.exposure.include:
        - mappings
        - health
        - info
        - metrics
    endpoint:
        mappings.enabled: true
        info.enabled: true
        health.enabled: true
        metrics.enabled: true
    tracing:
        sampling:
            probability: 1.0
otel:
    resource.attributes:
        deployment.environment: dev
        service:
            name: my-app
            namespace: my-namespace

otel collector config is:
receivers:
    otlp:
        protocols:
            http:

exporters:
    debug:
        verbosity: detailed

service:
    pipelines:
        traces:
            receivers: [otlp]
            exporters: [debug]
        metrics:
            receivers: [otlp]
            exporters: [debug]
        logs:
            receivers: [otlp]
            exporters: [debug]

and otel docker logs are:
2024-12-02T12:43:45.877Z        info    service@v0.114.0/service.go:166 Setting up own telemetry...
2024-12-02T12:43:45.877Z        info    telemetry/metrics.go:70 Serving metrics {"address": "localhost:8888", "metrics level": "Normal"}
2024-12-02T12:43:45.877Z        info    builders/builders.go:26 Development component. May change in the future.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "debug"}
2024-12-02T12:43:45.877Z        info    builders/builders.go:26 Development component. May change in the future.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "debug"}
2024-12-02T12:43:45.877Z        info    builders/builders.go:26 Development component. May change in the future.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "debug"}
2024-12-02T12:43:45.878Z        info    service@v0.114.0/service.go:238 Starting otelcol-contrib...     {"Version": "0.114.0", "NumCPU": 6}
2024-12-02T12:43:45.878Z        info    extensions/extensions.go:39     Starting extensions...
2024-12-02T12:43:45.878Z        info    otlpreceiver@v0.114.0/otlp.go:169       Starting HTTP server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "metrics", "endpoint": "localhost:4318"}
2024-12-02T12:43:45.878Z        info    service@v0.114.0/service.go:261 Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I faced the same issue where logs weren’t exporting,the issue was resolved by adding the endpoint property to the OTLP receiver configuration:
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

